# 'The process cannot access the file 'logs\dashboard.log' because it is being used by another process.' in a multi Task environment

Tags: c#

I have the following variable:

```
private readonly object fileLock = new object ();
```

used in the following function:

```
public void LogRaw (string message)
{
    lock (fileLock)
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter (Filename, true))
        {
            streamWriter.Write (message);
            streamWriter.Flush ();
            streamWriter.Close ();
            streamWriter.Dispose ();
        }
    }
}
```

This function is called by different Tasks executed at the same time. I don't understand why after a while I am receiving this exception:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'logs\dashboard.log' because it is being used by another process.'

since I am using the `lock` keyword and since inside the function I close and dispose the `streamWriter`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: Just to clarify, this is a single application with multiple Tasks and therefore multiple threads, but the application is one, I am not running multiple instances of the same app.
Furthermore the Logger class is instantiated only once and reused by the various Tasks that need it (maybe like a singleton).

Comment: using, Close & Dispose are redundant

Comment: Use a lock so two processes don't run the code at the same time.    It is possible that when one process is writing the second is try to open file use new StreamWriter.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: that `lock` will only work in the context of one application. So when you have multiple application run, you will have all of them try place an in process lock on that object NOT on the file. lock is not a OS or FileSystem concept it is a programming concept and only used when running into Threading problems (which has been solved by Async so very rarlery now a days) The error message could not be any more in your face. "The process cannot access the file" because another process is using it, in your case StreamWriter.

Comment: Unfortunately dealing with files is quite a tedious task. Look at some source code in logging frameworks maybe you will find some inspiration. Usually they do Buffering, where a process constantly tries to open a file and dump text to it and release it quickly, so another application can do the same. Exceptions are caught and treated to wait on AccessViolations, Thread Waiting, maybe some C# SystemFIleWatcher events for a more reactive solution. If that sound to much then just write to separate files, and have something read those and merge into one. Or maybe just into a Database.

Comment: The lock will only work with one instance of a class unless the method is static.

Comment: You should also be aware that adding a lock into this code is likely going to significantly impact performance. Only one thread can write the log at one one time now, this is likely going ot become a performance bottleneck. There is almost certainly a better solution to this problem, wether that is using a proper multi threaded data store (like SQL) or a logging library like [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) that deals with this for you.

Comment: Just to answer all these coments at once:
1) This is an application with multiple Tasks and therefore multiple threads, but it is one application, not multiple instances of the same application.
2) The Logger class is only instantiated once, it is static and the Tasks use it.

Comment: If you had only one instance of that lock object, your problem wouldn't exist, so clearly that is not the case. Or, you're opening that file somewhere else as well.

Comment: You state that the `Logger` class is `static` but how come your lock and method are not? Does that even compile? Just make your lock object static to start with...

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia you misunderstood: the instantiation is static, not the class. it is instantiated as `public static Logger Logger {get;private set;} = null;`

Comment: So, it is a singleton. You are still better off using a well known logging framework that can handle these types of issues. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen now that you wrote it, I'll check when I receive the exception in which part of the code it happens... my bad for not having checked...

Comment: erm...i didn't misunderstand, you just didn't describe it correctly... you stated Logger class is static...

Comment: Given your edit we're going to need a more concrete example. How do you create your `Task` objects? How and when do you instanciate your class? How do you inject this into your `Task`s? etc...

Comment: The issue will still be the same ultimately, somehow, somewhere you don't have a single lock so multiple threads can access your protected code.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia sorry, in the comment I wrote it correctly, in the Edit of the question I wrote it wrongly :(

Comment: I edited your question accordingly...

Comment: That's the only method that writes to the file. I also used CTRL+SHIFT+F to search the entire solution for `Write` and I only use it inside that lock...
However I create the Logger class inside the Application_Startup event handler. The tasks are instantiated like this:
`Task strategyTask = new Task (new Action (s.Run));strategyTask.Start ();` and inside the `s.Run()` the logging happens.

One thing that comes to my mind is that the file is created inside a directory that is monitored by OneDrive ... could it be the cause?

Comment: @ppumkin I could add a table inside the sqlite database I am using, but I thought that using a file is easier and faster to read than a database table.

Comment: FIles may be faster and easier... but one file for all applications is harder.. that is why databases were created to handle this scenario. multiple files is still a good solution and can be faster than db until there are too many files. The reason we no longer recommend using files is because we have a ton of great light weight databases like SQLite that is free, fast, robust and easy to use.

Comment: @ppumkin what I meant with read, was for a human, but I see your point... probably is a better approach. I can do it, but then I will probably have to build some sort of interface to read the rows from the database. (That's what I was trying to avoid... eheheh)

Comment: You can use a tool like sqlitebrowser.org and give users a readonly connection string. Besides, the time you spent trying to solve this file headache you would have written a quick console app by now to read the database and dump a text file for a person when they needed it :D

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out that it was OneDrive fault. I paused it and run the application for about 10 minutes and didn't receive any exception (Before it was happening after 1 minute max). As soon as I resumed OneDrive (with the application running), after 5 or 6 seconds I got the exception. I didn't think about OneDrive because I thought it is built to handle such a situation, but probably not.

Comment: Oh my god.. seriously  hahahah

Comment: Obviously it will fail less often... But still fail because your code should be from time to time try to write to the same file in parallel. OneDrive (or anything else that would slow writes down - usually AV programs good for that) will make errors more frequent and easier to reproduce.